# undefined attribute in use of $controllerProvider in Angular

Tags: angularjs

I'm a newbie in Angular, i whant to make use of **$controllerProvider**, i see an example like my code, but the attribute register got undefined:

```
var appTmw = angular.module('appTmw', ['ui.router']);

appTmw.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $controllerProvider) {

    appTmw.register = {
        controller: $controllerProvider.register
    };
})
```

and here, a register of controller, the register attribute got undefined:

```
appTmw.register.controller('CustomersController', ['$scope', 'config', 'dataService',
   function ($scope, config, dataService) {

      //Controller code goes here
   }]);
```

what a problem with the code?

Comment: appTmwCtrl is a old module reference that's had a set conteiners, i will edit the question to remove this piece.

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/dwahlin/dynamically-loading-controllers-and-views-with-angularjs-and-requirejs

Answer (score 0):

controllerProvider is the $controller service used by Angular to create new controllers:
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$controllerProvider

If you are new to angular I suggest you to use the **standard** way to create a controller:

```
var appTmw = angular.module('appTmw', ['ui.router']);

appTmw.controller('controllerName', function($scope){

//your code for the controller here

});
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: i aways use this way, i want to learn this new mode, to avoid many controllers in a single file.